# Add item to a List<Tuple> inside another list

Tags: c#, list

I made a scratch application to mimic some behavior I need to incorporate into a web service that returns data from a database and uses the returned data for creating dynamic Google Charts.

So far here is what I have

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var tupleMissingBeginning = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>
        {
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 5, 1), 25),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 6, 1), 35)
        };

        var tupleMissingMiddle = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>
        {
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2016, 12, 1), 25),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), 20),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 2, 1), 30),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 3, 1), 25),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 6, 1), 35)
        };

        var tupleMissingEnd = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>
        {
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), 20),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 2, 1), 30),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 3, 1), 25)
        };

        var tupleMissingBeginningAndEnd = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>
        {
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 3, 1), 20),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 4, 1), 30),
            Tuple.Create( new DateTime(2017, 5, 1), 25)
        };

        DateTime minDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        DateTime maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;

        Console.WriteLine("MinDate: " + minDate);
        Console.WriteLine("MaxDate: " + maxDate);
        Console.WriteLine("");

        List<List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>> myList = new List<List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>>();

        myList.Add(tupleMissingBeginning);
        myList.Add(tupleMissingMiddle);
        myList.Add(tupleMissingEnd);
        myList.Add(tupleMissingBeginningAndEnd);

        foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item[i] + " . . . . MinDate: " + minDate + ", MaxDate: " + maxDate);
                if (item[i].Item1 < minDate)
                {
                    minDate = item[i].Item1;
                }
                if (item[i].Item1 > maxDate)
                {
                    maxDate = item[i].Item1;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("MinDate: " + minDate);
        Console.WriteLine("MaxDate: " + maxDate);


        foreach (var item in myList) // for each list<tuple<DateTime, int>> in myList,
        {

            while (minDate <= maxDate)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(minDate);
                minDate = minDate.AddMonths(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: image of output]

Somewhere and somehow in that second loop I need to use the minDate and maxDate to be able to inspect whether or not an item exists in that spot for that particular list.  Basically, since the minDate is 12/1/2016 and maxDate is 6/1/2017 (these are just arbitrary dates by the way, can be anything) I need to make sure that each `List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>` contains the same number of elements and if at that index there was nothing present, I can insert a 0 for the first day of that month.

I have tried using a for loop that uses the raw DateTimes as the indexer and condition as well as just using the months but ran into problems with new years and the overall process of inserting the values.

Edit: Here is what I currently have:

```
        foreach (var item in myList) // for each list<tuple<DateTime, int>> in myList,
        {
            DateTime newDate = minDate;
            while (newDate <= maxDate)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(minDate);
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
                {
                    bool containsDate = item.Any(D => D.Item1 == newDate);
                    if (!containsDate)
                    {
                        item.Insert(i, new Tuple<DateTime, int>(newDate, 0));
                    }
                }
                newDate = newDate.AddMonths(1);
            }
        }
```

which produces the following output:
[image: second output image]

So it's just about there, it adds all the 0s it just doesn't put them in the correct spots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out your problem. In general it is difficult to modify what you are iterating through with `foreach`.

This solution will iterate through every month between the min and the max. It will then iterate through every list. If the list doesn't have that month then it is inserted into the list.

```
for (int i = 0; minDate <= maxDate; i++)
{
    for (int list = 0; list < myList.Count; list++)
    {
        if (myList[list].Count <= i || myList[list][i].Item1 != minDate)
        {
            myList[list].Insert(i, Tuple.Create(minDate, 0));
        }
    }

    minDate = minDate.AddMonths(1);
}
```

You can also use the date as the iterator and sort at the end:

```
for (var i = minDate; i <= maxDate; i = i.AddMonths(1))
{
    for (int list = 0; list < myList.Count; list++)
    {
        if (!myList[list].Any(tuple => tuple.Item1 == i))
        {
            myList[list].Add(Tuple.Create(i, 0));
        }
    }
}

myList.ForEach(item => item.Sort((x, y) => x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1)));
```

You can also find the min and max by first flattening:

```
var dates = myList.SelectMany(list => list).Select(item => item.Item1);
minDate = dates.Min();
maxDate = dates.Max();
```

Comment: I was so close!  I'll add where I was in an edit to the original post.  Thanks so much for your solution.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: Adam, thanks again.  The edit went above and beyond what I was looking for.  Very helpful stuff!